# my click event with on method not working after clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

it barely working, it worked for the 1st time, but not the next hit..

```
$('.edit').on('click', itemClick);
```

itemClick is my custom function..

http://jsfiddle.net/nurullia/ndCty/1/

Comment: Please post the relevant code here, not just point to jsfiddle. What if jsfiddle goes dead?

Comment: Try commenting this //input.keydown(inputKeydown); in this itemClick function,

Comment: while i'd agree inputKeydown isn't defined and throws errors it's not the problem.  as @Sushanth pointed out, objects are being dynamically re-added without rebinding so you'd have to delegate the event; short of that, just clear out the text and re-add the text afterwards rather than removing and re-adding DOM elements that needs new events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be adding elements dynamically to your page.

Try **delegating the event.**

Replace

```
$('.edit').on('click', itemClick);
```

with

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', itemClick);
```

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Event when clicked on li
    $(document).on('click', 'li', function () {
        $('li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    // Delegate the .edit event
    $(document).on('click', '.edit', itemClick);
    // Delegate the input event
    $(document).on('blur', 'input', editInputBlur);

    function itemClick(e) {
        // Stop the propagation when you click on edit
        e.stopPropagation();
        var $this = $(this),
            // Find the closest li
            $li = $this.closest('li'),
            // Get the text
            txt = $li.find('.items').text();
        // Add and remove class for li
        $li.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        // Empty the li
        $li.empty();
        // Create input and append it to $li
        var $input = $("<input type='text' maxlength='30'/>").val(txt);

        $input.appendTo($li).focus();
    }


    function editInputBlur(e) {
        // You can use $(this) here directly as that is the event target
        var $this = $(this),
            v = $this.val(); // new edited value

        if (v.trim() !== "") {
            var html = '';
            html += "<a href='#'><span class='items'>" + v + "</span></a>";
            html += "<a href='#'><span class='edit'>edit</span></a>";
            var $a = $(html);
            // Use closest so that it does not break if any
            // extra container is added later
            $this.closest('li').append($a);
            $this.remove();
        }
    }

});
```

### **[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ndCty/7/)**

Comment: it worked! thanks! but still it seem like a bug, because it seem like require 2 clicks instead of one, it needed to be click on the 'li' then the link.. any idea?

Comment: It is because of this condition `var $this = $(e.target).closest('li.active');`  You are only selecting if the `li` has active class. So the condition satisfies only if you click on the `li` first right

Comment: I remove the class 'active', it worked perfectly now! thanks!

Comment: @NurulLia.. Check updated post and fiddle.. Always a better idea to delegate the events. Also move the blur event outside